# Anylogic: Fill Array values faster

Tags: anylogic

I do try to fill array-parameters of the type double[8760] at the beginning of my simulation from an internal database table. This table has the column hourofyear and a column for every parameter. My code is working but processing the data very slow:

```
for (int row_counter=0;row_counter<= 8759; row_counter++) {
ProfileParameterA[row_counter] = selectFrom(data)
.where(data.hourofyear.eq(row_counter))
.uniqueResult(data.a, double.class);
ProfileParameterB[row_counter] = selectFrom(data)
.where(data.hourofyear.eq(row_counter))
.uniqueResult(data.b, double.class);    
}
```

Any suggestion on how to improve the import to load the data of the table quicker into the parameters?

Thanks a lot.

Heinz-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ProfileParameterA = selectFrom(data)
    .where(data.hourofyear.eq(row_counter))
    .list(data.a).stream().mapToDouble( d -> d ).toArray();

ProfileParameterB = selectFrom(data)
    .where(data.hourofyear.eq(row_counter))
    .list(data.b).stream().mapToDouble( d -> d ).toArray();
```

It is part of [Java Stream API](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm), convenient for work with lists, arrays, collections in functional style.

Comment: Hi Gregory,
works fine, thanks. I just had to shorten the Code into :
ProfileParameterA = selectFrom(data)
    .list(data.a).stream().mapToDouble( d -> d ).toArray();
as there is no for-loop anymore. (Guess this just works, because my data is already in the order I need it) Thanks a lot!